# Including Session storage date and/or time in prompt output

Tags: actions-on-google

I am developing an Actions on Google action and have two slots in a scene.  One is called `book_day` of type `actions.type.Date` and the other is called `book_time` of type `actions.type.Time`.  In my scene, when the condition shows that the slots have been filled, I complete with a response prompt of:

```
Your class has been booked for $session.params.book_day at $session.params.book_time.
```

What gets returned to the user is:

```
Your class has been booked for 2020-12-28T12:00:00Z at 2020-12-28T02:00:00Z.
```

When I supplied "Today" and "2" for the date and time.  When I look in the simulator, I see that my session storage is:

```
{
  "book_day": {
    "month": 12,
    "day": 28,
    "year": 2020
  },
  "book_time": {
    "minutes": 0,
    "seconds": 0,
    "nanos": 0,
    "hours": 2
  }
}
```

With this pre-amble, here is the question:

I had assumed that my definitions would have allowed Actions on Google to recognize that the values included in the prompt outputs were of type "Date" and "Time" and hence output Date only and Time only in the response.  For example, I would have expected:

```
Your class has been booked for 2020-12-28 at 2:00.
```

What we are finding is that a full date/time (which is meaningless) is output.  Is there any guidance on working with date/time output values in prompts?

Comment: Did you have any fulfillment code, or did you do everything in the prompt definition?

Comment: I did not use any fulfillment code.  All definitions were made in the prompt definitions only.